# The label size of each image is different using Pytorch Dataloader

Tags: python

Collate function

```
def func(batch):
    img, label = zip(*batch)
    img_list = []
    label_list = []
    for i, l in enumerate(label):
        img_ptr = torch.full((l.size(0), 1), i, dtype=torch.int32)
        l = torch.cat((img_ptr, l), dim=1)
        return torch.stack(img, 0), torch.cat(label, 0)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=size, shuffle=True, collate_fn=func)
    # test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=size, shuffle=True, collate_fn=func)
    count = 1
    # Display image and label.
    for index, data in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        features, labels = data
        print(f"Feature batch shape: {features.size()}")
        print(f"Labels batch shape: {labels.size()}")
        count = count + 1
    print(count)
```

Result

```
Feature batch shape: torch.Size([2, 3, 320, 320])
Labels batch shape: torch.Size([555, 3])
2
```

I insert 2 image with each annotation file and they cant seprate each time,it combine 239,316 to 555
There is a problem in the return function
Please help help help me to deal with this proble!

It can be load with different label size of each image